# Bootstrap hover and click event conflict when used togather to have both hover and click event for menus

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap version 2.3 for the first time. So far it has not been going well since it is my first time implementing bootstrap responsive design.

I have a navigation menu with sub menus and I have been asked to have both `click` & `hover` functionality for these menu so that when website is viewed on Desktop it used hover for view sub menus and use Click event when being viewed on mobile devices.

After few problems I managed to make it work so that I have both events working for Menu navigation, but I have a problem where I am still stuck.

The link for the demo of what I have so far is here:

http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/TestPage.htm

Right now on mobile devices, I have to double click the menu and wait a half second before the submenu will open. I am not able to figure out how to show the submenu on a single click from the user.

I have been struggling with this problem for two days so I would appreciate help with this problem.

Reference: I am using the following theme: `http://htmlstream.com/unify/` but I have modified code a bit to have have hover Functionality.`

The hover event is based on this: `https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown`

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually accomplish this with CSS alone, and not have to worry about rendering JS for this one. Make use of the `:hover` pseudo class on your menu item and apply a display block to the adjacent "menu items" of the selector when hovered (of course you can also add css-transitions for animations - keep in mind though css transitions won't be supported on non-HTML5 browsers).

The `:hover` pseudo class is activated on touch devices on the first tap, and tapping anywhere else unattaches the hover state. See the following article, which relays the same message: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/#toc-4

Here is a working fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/2eaNY/) demonstrating this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I have implement your idea, It works fine but creates other issues like when i click on the `Menu One` then it becomes hard to click on the `Menu Three` when i click one menu three while menu one is open it does function but so quick that it rather opens the `Directory` page on the mobile version collapse.  I will see if i can add delay of make it work like a collapsible menu... link http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/TestPage2.htm